# Error while uploading image in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

In below code I am trying to upload an image but it shows the following error.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\Work\xampp\tmp\php8A66.tmp' to 'images\uploads\slider\'1413996794_::1.jpeg'' in D:\Work\xampp\htdocs\project\aad\slider.php on line 35

I think the problem is in function named move_uploaded_file(); php function.

Directory where should save that image is available in project folder.

I am trying to solve this issue What step should I take?

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $imageName = $_POST['imageName'];
    $imageFile = $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['imageFile']['size'];
    $imageType = $_FILES['imageFile']['type'];

    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $time = time();

    if($imageType == 'image/gif'){
        $ext = '.gif';
    }elseif($imageType == 'image/png'){
        $ext = '.png';
    }elseif($imageType == 'image/jpg'){
        $ext = '.jpg';
    }elseif($imageType == 'image/jpeg'){
        $ext = '.jpeg';
    }

    $imageFileName = $time.'_'.$ipAddress.$ext;

    //$dir = "images\uploads\slider\$imageFileName";
    $dir = "images\uploads\slider\".$imageFileName;

    if($imageName !== ''){
        if($imageSize < '200000000'){
            if($imageType == 'image/gif' || $imageType == 'image/png' || $imageType == 'image/jpeg' || $imageType == 'image/jpg'){
                if(move_uploaded_file($imageFile, $dir)){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO slider VALUES('', '$imageName', '$imageFileName', '$imageSize', '$dir')";
                    $mysql_query = mysql_query($query);
                    if($mysql_query){
                        $msg = 'Image Uploaded Successfully';
                    }else{
                        $msg = 'Image Uploading Failed.';
                    }
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Error while uploading file, Please try again.';
                }
            }else{
                $msg = 'Image type should be .gif, .png, .jpg or .jpeg.';
            }
        }else{
            $msg = 'Image size is too large.';
        }
    }else{
        $msg = 'Image name cannot be empty.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked your logs? What is the actual error message provided? My guess is that it is a permissions issue on the destination directory.

Comment: Those colons `:` have something to do with your renaming the file using `time()` and the IP address. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- After adding error reporting code to the top it still shows the same error. And yes time() is used in naming the file. And I dont see an colons : in my code.

Comment: @MattClark If I change `$dir = "images\uploads\slider\".$imageFileName;` to $dir = "images\uploads\slider\pic.png"; it saves the image and all uploading works correctly. From this step this is confirmed that  destination directory has no permissions issue. But the problem is in this case all the images will be named pic.png.

Comment: Upon first glance at the question I thought it would be a permission issue, I see now that the issue is with the file name, that is why I am saying to please see my edited answer below.

Comment: Just a hunch. Try changing this line `if(move_uploaded_file($imageFile, $dir)){` to `if(move_uploaded_file($imageFile, "$dir")){` adding quotes around `$dir`, as per what the manual shows http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now I have minor issue in this code while sending to mysql. eg when I echo $dir in code it shows images\uploads\slider\1414000033.jpeg. But in Mysql table it show it like this imagesuploadsslider1414000033.jpeg all the slashes are gone in database.

Comment: Please take it up with Matt since you accepted the answer. I knew the \'s in your `$dir = "images\uploads\slider\".$imageFileName;` would be a big problem and would need to be `/` - The \ are mostly used for Windows system where you need to use `c:\\folder\\filename.xxx`

Comment: @MattClark Now I have minor issue in this code while sending to mysql. eg when I echo $dir in code it shows images\uploads\slider\1414000033.jpeg. But in Mysql table it show it like this imagesuploadsslider1414000033.jpeg all the slashes are gone in database.

Comment: **I can confirm** that the root of the problem would have been to change `"images\uploads\slider\".$imageFileName;` to `"images/uploads/slider/".$imageFileName;`. I don't want to undermine Matt's answer, but that was unnecessary adding the extra function.

Comment: I'm under the impression that in changing it to `"images/uploads/slider/".$imageFileName;` also fixed the DB stuff ;)

Comment: Your Comment solved MySQL DB Problem.

Comment: It also would have and should have solved everything really. I'll bet that, if you change your entire code to just that single line, it would have solved both your upload and DB problem, right? I am confident that I am. I should have made it an answer from the beginning. Gotta love "after sales service" ;) not many go the "extra mile".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your error message.

You are trying to save the file to this location

```
images\uploads\slider\'1413996794_::1.jpeg
```

Does `D:\Work\xampp\htdocs\project\aad\images\uploads\slider\` exist in your current working tree?

Also, you have an `'` and 2 `:`'s in your filename, which are invalid in a file name.

**EDIT**

Firstly, you must remove the `:`'s from the ip address so they do not get carried into the file name.

Secondly, it would appear to me that you are having an issue with the `'` because you have not properly escaped your `\`'s.

Try this:

```
// Remove any instance of ':'
$imageFileName = str_replace(":", "", $imageFileName);

// Set the directory, escaping backslashes
$dir = "images\\uploads\\slider\\" . $imageFileName;
```

Comment: Sir, Why do you added double slashes in $dir  \\?

Comment: A backslash is used for escaping characters inside of quotes. Ie: `$something = "i am text \" with quotes\" inside of quotes.";` In your above code, the "\" are an escape character, with text, or in your case, a `"` following. By adding the additional backslashes, you escape and add a literal '\' to the string.

Comment: [See the PHP String documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: If you are using single quotes around the string instead or double quotes, you will not need to use the '\' as an escape character.